# Extract default css CKEDITOR

Tags: css, ckeditor

Is there a way to extract or get the default CSS for CKEDITOR, i have been looking for it  but can not find it, i like to use this css in another page without the editor working just the css style

Comment: The [documentation for `contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) might be helpful.

Comment: Or maybe: [How to apply ckeditor css to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859370/how-to-apply-ckeditor-css-to-output)