# how to add custom class & style in ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I use ckeditor5, how can I customize it to and make it add class dynamically?

currently I am using following module,

[npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular)

ex.

> `<blockquote>`value `</blockquote>`

i want it to add class every time dynamically the blockquote is used

> `<blockquote class="blockquote">`Value`</blockquote>`

Comment: My friend here you could find a solution to your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859370/how-to-apply-ckeditor-css-to-output?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

The CKEditor 5  for Angular can be styled using 2 things>

the component stylesheet or 
using a global stylesheet.

check how to set the CKEditor 5 component’s height using these two approaches.

via the component stylesheet
First, create a (S)CSS file in the parent component’s directory and style the given editor’s part preceded by the :host and ::ng-deep pseudo

```
/app/app.component.css */


:host ::ng-deep .ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Then in the parent component add the relative path to the above stylesheet:

```
/* src/app/app.component.ts */

@Component( {
    // ...
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
} )
```

Setting the height via a global stylesheet
To style the component using a global stylesheet, first, create it:

```
/* src/styles.css */

.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Then, add it in the angular.json configuration file:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "options": {
            "styles": [
                { "input": "src/styles.css" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I want to add class to html tag which are in editor

Comment: This appears to be a copy/paste of the documentation of styling. Not very helpful or on topic.

Comment: you could name it as the future way of sharing knowledge :)